# Computation of the expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Assuming points are sampled from a uniform distribution on $ [0,1] $. If we sample $10$ values and compute their mean value $u$, the expectation of $u$ is $1/2$. However, if we sample $10$ values and compute the average $\hat{u}$ of the $9$ smallest of them, what is the expectation of $\hat{u}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "9 smaller values"? Are you saying that $\hat{\mu}$ is the expectation of the 9 smallest values out of the 10 that are sampled?

Comment: Yes, in the first one we utilize 10 values to compute the mean(non-bias) , and in the second one, we only utilize 9 smaller value out of 10 values to compute the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the derivation more clear, let us replace the specific value $10$ by some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now let $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim U(0,1)$ be independent and uniformly distributed in the unit interval $[0,1]$. Then the random variable you are interested in is the average of the $n-1$ smallest $X_i$.

Writing $X^\star := \max_{1\le k\le n} X_k$, we obtain the sum over the smallest $n-1$ of the $X_i$ by subtracting $X^\star$ from the sum over all $X_i$, thus the quantity of interest can be written as $$
M := \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - X^\star\right),$$
the expected value of which is $$\mathbb{E} [M] = \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \frac{n}{2} - \mathbb{E}\left[X^\star\right]\right).$$
Hence it remains to find the expected maximum of $n$ independent $U(0,1)$-variables. This can be shown to be $\mathbb{E}\left[X^\star\right] = \frac{n}{n+1}$ (a derivation of which I would be happy to add if you're interested), giving us the final result
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[M]
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \frac n2 - \frac{n}{n+1}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \frac{n(n+1) - 2n}{2(n+1)}\\
&= \frac 12\frac{n}{n+1}.
\end{align*}
As expected, this is smaller than but gets increasingly close to $\frac 12$ as $n$ increases. In your case, where $n = 10$, this becomes $\mathbb{E}[M] = 10/22 \approx 0.45$.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I have got it now.

Comment: Hi, peter, I have a question: we can obtain the expectation of the top 1 value (the largest value) as $\mathbb{E}(X^*)=\frac{n}{n+1}$, But if we want to calculate the expectation of the top 10% lager value, how should we do? Could you give some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if you have time, could you see this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3826941/how-to-compute-the-expectation-of-this-problem, and the answer under it is not correct. It is similar to this question, but it involves two random variables and the top X% percentage instead of top 1 larger value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Refrain The question gets much harder if you consider the average of more than just the singular highest value (like the two or three largest values, or the largest tenth, as in your case). I will think about it if I find the time, though I am quite busy at the moment so I can't make any promises.

Comment: thank you a lot!